# Apache Cordova iOS Remote Build

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

We have a project that is in it's early stages of creation in Visual Studio 2017 using Apache Cordova. The app builds and runs in web browsers, android simulators/devices and a macbook pro.

The macbook pro is not a viable solution so are trying to get the remote build working on a Mac Mini. No matter what we couldn't get this working so made the decision to wipe the Mac Mini and start from scratch. After a hard drive wipe and fresh install of osx Sierra we are still experiencing the same problem.

I've copied below the log that is produced upon build on the Mac. In the folder the log is created in if I navigate to platforms and then open up the xcode project and run that it runs fine on the mac. I'm at a loss as to why this can't be run from VS2017 through remote tools.

```
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
Copying plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" => "/Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist"
Copying plugin "remote/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist" => "/Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist"
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
No version specified for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support, retrieving version from config.xml
No version for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support saved in config.xml
Attempting to use npm info for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support to choose a compatible release
npm info for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support did not contain any engine info. Fetching latest release
Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support"
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" via npm
Copying plugin "/Users/macmini/.npm/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/0.2.3/package" => "/Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support"
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
cordova platform add ios
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_platform_add": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-execute-bit-fix.js
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_platform_add": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-remove-plugin-json.js
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Adding ios project...
PlatformApi successfully found for platform ios
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: io.cordova.myappd7d4a1
    Name: SeaComply.Cordova
Copying iOS template project to /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.2.0
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/exec.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/exec.js (new file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova-js-src/platform.js platforms/ios/www/cordova-js-src/platform.js (new file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova.js platforms/ios/www/cordova.js (updated file)
  copy  www/css/index.css platforms/ios/www/css/index.css (updated file)
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/dist
  copy  www/dist/674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot platforms/ios/www/dist/674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot (new file)
  copy  www/dist/89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg platforms/ios/www/dist/89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg (new file)
  copy  www/dist/912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg platforms/ios/www/dist/912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg (new file)
  copy  www/dist/b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf platforms/ios/www/dist/b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf (new file)
  copy  www/dist/main-client.js platforms/ios/www/dist/main-client.js (new file)
  copy  www/dist/main-client.js.map platforms/ios/www/dist/main-client.js.map (new file)
  copy  www/dist/vendor-manifest.json platforms/ios/www/dist/vendor-manifest.json (new file)
  copy  www/dist/vendor.css platforms/ios/www/dist/vendor.css (new file)
  copy  www/dist/vendor.css.map platforms/ios/www/dist/vendor.css.map (new file)
  copy  www/dist/vendor.js platforms/ios/www/dist/vendor.js (new file)
  copy  www/dist/vendor.js.map platforms/ios/www/dist/vendor.js.map (new file)
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/images
  copy  www/images/cordova.png platforms/ios/www/images/cordova.png (new file)
  rmdir  platforms/ios/www/img (no source)
  delete platforms/ios/www/img/logo.png (no source)
  copy  www/index.html platforms/ios/www/index.html (updated file)
  rmdir  platforms/ios/www/js (no source)
  delete platforms/ios/www/js/index.js (no source)
  mkdir platforms/ios/www/scripts
  copy  www/scripts/application.js platforms/ios/www/scripts/application.js (new file)
  copy  www/scripts/application.js.map platforms/ios/www/scripts/application.js.map (new file)
  copy  www/scripts/startup.js platforms/ios/www/scripts/startup.js (new file)
  copy  www/scripts/startup.js.map platforms/ios/www/scripts/startup.js.map (new file)
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "io.cordova.myappd7d4a1" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/SeaComply.Cordova-Info.plist
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "SeaComply.Cordova")
Updating icons at platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
  copy  res/icons/ios/icon-60.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-60.png (new file)
Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-667h.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-736h.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape-736h.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Landscape~ipad.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait~ipad.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default@2x~iphone.png (updated file)
  copy  res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default~iphone.png (updated file)
Prepared iOS project successfully
Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" following successful platform add of ios
Found variables for "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser". Processing as cli_variables.
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for ios
Running command: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-inappbrowser on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-inappbrowser on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-inappbrowser on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" following successful platform add of ios
Found variables for "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support". Processing as cli_variables.
Installing "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" for ios
Running command: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" following successful platform add of ios
Found variables for "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Processing as cli_variables.
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Running command: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/version 
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on ios.
Beginning processing of action stack for ios project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on ios platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-execute-bit-fix.js
Resolving module name for q => q
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support for hook "before_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support/hooks/hook-res-native.js
Processing res/native for ios
Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova_plugins.js platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js (updated file)
  copy  platforms/ios/platform_www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js platforms/ios/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js (updated file)
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "io.cordova.myappd7d4a1" and iOS Bundle Version "1.0.0" to /Users/macmini/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1794/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/SeaComply.Cordova-Info.plist
iOS Product Name has not changed (still "SeaComply.Cordova")
Updating icons at platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/
Updating splash screens at platforms/ios/SeaComply.Cordova/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/
Prepared iOS project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Saving ios@4.2.0 into platforms.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
Failed to build app for buildNumber 1794:
```

Thanks.